# Como deixar uma div ao lado da outra?

Tags: html, css, css3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        }
    body {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .loren{
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .ipsulum{
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
    p {
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 15pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="loren">
<p>Loren</p>
</div>
<div class="ipsulum">
<p>Ipsulum</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você deveria elaborar mais a pergunta, mostre o que tentou, explique melhor a pergunta, não ponha só código e espere obter resposta. Você deverá usar `float:left`

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de os colocar lado a lado é com `float:left`. Aproveito para dizer a propriedade `left` não tem efeito para elementos posicionados de forma estática como é o seu caso, e que `display:block` é o `display` por defeito para um `<div>`

Exemplo com `float:left`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.loren{
    float:left; /*<---*/
    width: 50%;
}
.ipsulum{
    float:left; /*<---*/
    width: 50%;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="loren">
    <p>Loren</p>
</div>
<div class="ipsulum">
    <p>Ipsulum</p>
</div>
```

Outra forma de fazer o mesmo é com `display:flex` que implica criar um elemento que englobe os dois divs:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.loren{
    width: 50%;
}
.ipsulum{
    width: 50%;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}

.conteudo {
    display:flex; /*<--*/
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo"> <!--div para conter os dois já existentes-->
  <div class="loren">
      <p>Loren</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ipsulum">
      <p>Ipsulum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentação:

- [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
- [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)